# Как переместить все файлы webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Как с помощью webpack 4 используя плагин `htmlwebpackplugin` "переместить" все файлы из одной директории в другую ?

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            hash: false,
            template: `views/index.html`,
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
```

Вот делаю так, но это для одного файла. А по-другому не получается

Answer (score 1):

```
 const path = require('path');
 const fs = require('fs'); 


    //получаем все файлы
    let arrayHtml = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'путь к папке с файлами')),

      // В данной функции прокручиваем их в цикле получаем массив
      function htmlPlugins() {
        return arrayHtml.map(s => {
          return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: s,
            filename: s
          })
        })
      })
    };

    //  И потом сонкатинируем в массив plugins 
    plugins: [].concat(htmlPlugins())
```

Второй вариант в ручную...

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: false,
    template: `views/index.html`,
    filename: './index.html'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: false,
    template: `views/page1.html`,
    filename: './page1.html'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    hash: false,
    template: `views/page2.html`,
    filename: './page2.html'
  }),
]
```

Comment: спасибо большое, попробую!

Comment: не получается.. let arrayHtml = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/views')); сделал так, потом записал функцию, а дальше сыпет ошибки

Comment: ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules\other.html' in 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules':
  Error: Can't resolve 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules\other.html' in 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules'

Comment: вернее, он их перемещает, но почему то выдает ошибки, и сам текст в html файлах стирает (пишет вместо него такое: Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules\index.html' in 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules':
  Error: Can't resolve 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules\index.html' in 'D:\JS_MODULES\jsmodules'
  
  - compiler.js:79 
    [jsmodules]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
  
  - Compiler.js:343 
    [jsmodules]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
  )

Comment: Это же `nodejs` , а модули для работы с файлами ты подключил?  `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: Да, конечно. Ошибки уже после запуска npm run dev выдает

Comment: Может из-за того, что у меня стили в один файл собираются, и этот файл подключается ко всем страницам?